# LDO pass transistor operation region

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo

I am studying about LDO and I came across this [App Note](https://www.analog.com/media/en/Other/Miscellaneous/PM_ldo_design_08451b.pdf)

While reading, I encountered the following questions.

At the end of first paragraph, they mention "This is a closed-loop system
based around two main poles, the internal pole of the error
amplifier/pass transistor and the external pole of the output capacitor’s equivalent series resistance (ESR.)"

1. What do they mean when they say, "two main poles?" What does it mean in electrical terms?
2. "PSRR is usually specified at a specific frequency,
   for example 60 dB rejection at 120 Hz." What do they mean by 60dB in terms of electrical voltage?

Comment: This App Note is about **design**, a "pole" is a well known concept in the design of filters and feedback systems. It goes to far to explain that here, instead I suggest you study a book on **Analog circuit design**. The same is true for "dB". All in all you're trying to understand an App Note that was written for engineers with a background in Analog Design. If you don't have that background the App Note will raise more questions than it can answer.

Comment: Could you please help with my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Poles are a property of a control system transfer function, they are the points on a complex plane where the transfer function goes to infinity, and electrical system can be analyzed like this as well. It basically means that the capacitor ESR and capacitance need to be carefully selected for stable operation. Wrongly selected capacitor can lead to unstable operation, it might even oscillate just by itself.

2) It means whatever the ripple amplitude is at regulator input, it will be 60 dB less on the output.That's a factor of 1000 said in a convenient fashion.

Comment: How can the capacitance and its ESR oscillate by itself without any input and how to understand the first pole i.e. pass transistor? And for the second point, if the ripple amplitude at the input is 1000mV, we would get a ripple amplitude of 1mV at the output and specifically at 120Hz and no other frequency? Am i right ?

Comment: Capacitor does not oscillate by itself - remember the capacitor is connected to the regulator which is the active component with feedback that drives the capacitor and load. So a badly chosen capacitor will make the whole system to oscillate.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. What about the pass transistor pole and my comment regarding the PSRR

Comment: The ripple rejection is just measured at 120 Hz input because some countries have 60 Hz mains frequency, it is assumed that regulator is used in a full bridge rectified power supply. Other frequencies have other attenuations, and high enough frequencies may not be attenuated at all or they might be even amplified.

Comment: Thank you. Pass transistor?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOdl45.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Regarding the PSRR: notice the 1Kohm from Vunregulated to the Zener reference. Assume the Zener has internal 10 ohm dynamic resistance. The delta_Vreference will be 1% of the Vunregulated, thus the **BEST** this voltage regulator PSRR can be is 40dB (100:1).

Now regarding the poles: there are a number of delays (causing phase shifts) in this circuit:

---- voltage divider output, the midpoint of R1 and R2

---- the shared emitters of Q1 and Q2

---- the gain_node, collectors of NPN Q1 and PNP Q5 plus gate of the large PMOS FET

---- the external Cload (with its ESR resistor, providing a rising-with-frequency response) which produces less delay at higher frequencies

Only the shared_emitter node is fast. Thus there are THREE slow nodes here.

I show a possible frequency compensation: C1 and R10, with 100 nanosecond time constant, and thus 1.6MHz F3dB. This may or may not be useful.

The large_area Pchannel MOSFET is a problem.

This "LDO" uses relatively high operating currents, so the FET gate capacitance can be slewed moderately quickly:

dV/dT = I/C = 45uA/45pF  = 1 Million volts per second.